# Regular Expression to extract numbers from string with special characters

Tags: php, regex

I have string like

> 8.123.351 (Some text here)

I have used the Regex

```
/([0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2,})+(\.[0-9]{2,})?)/
```

to take value "8.123.351" from string. It is working for the string given above.

But it is not working when the string without "." for example "179 (Some text here)".
I modified Regex to match this value also, but no success.

So can anyone suggest me the Regex to get numbers from strings like:

1. 8.123.351 (Some text here)
2. 179 (Some text here)
3. 179.123 (Some text here)
4. 179.1 (Some text here)

Comment: Can you provide more of an idea on the regular format of the numbers? What rules are in place? Can there be any number of `.`s, anywhere, can numbers be any size, length, etc?

Comment: @Leonard, Thanks for your comment. I have posted some example strings with numbers. The string has numbers with 2-3 digits, that is fixed. But multiple occurrence of numbers with "." in between is not fixed. So I need all numbers with "." or without it

Comment: The casual slang term “special characters” is not defined by the Unicode Standard. It’s too sloppy. All code points are special, or not-special, as the case may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very clear. I make some assumptions to create a pattern.

1. The numbers are at the start of the string
2. There is at least 1 digit and at most 3 digits before there is a dot

Now we create your expression

1. Match 1 to 3 digits at the start of the row

   ```
   /^\d{1,3}/
   ```
2. There is optionally (the `?` after the group) a dot and one to three more digits

   ```
   /^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})?/
   ```
3. This part with the dot can be repeated 0 or more times (replace the `?` with a `*`)

   ```
   /^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})*/
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30tfa)

If you want to read some basics about regular expressions, [I wrote a blog post about that](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4).

Comment: Thanks stema, it is more perfect expression than I prepared. And thanks for providing nice blog post about Regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
/([0-9]+[,\.]?)+/
```

matches all of your strings

By the way... your RegEx needs a point to match because `+` says 1 or more matches. `*` is 0 or more and `?` is 0 or 1

Comment: Thanks kuh-chan for showing me my mistake, It is working now. I can get all numbers from string with "." or without "." I have changed the regex and replace "+" with "*"

Comment: It may not be a problem, but this will also match `1.2.3. (some text)` so if that's a problem it's wrong

Comment: @Leonard Yes but the string will never have . after numbers that is 1.2.3. Thanks for your comment.